# Magento2 lake of baseurl in image src shows broken images in Magento2 backend Edit form

Tags: magento2

I have added a new file uploader field to magento admin form. It saves image correctly.But image is not showing in backend form due to absence of baseurl. Can you suggest showm solotion to it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup the system.xml correctly it should work out of the box:

```xml
<field id="bg_img" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Background image</label>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">vendor_your_dir_name</base_url>
    <validate>required-entry</validate>
    <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">vendor_your_dir_name</upload_dir>
</field>
```